# NoMethodError for relationship between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I am setting up a relationship between two of my models. A Patient Model and Worklist Model. My patient can belong to a worklist and a worklist can have many patients. In my form for patients I want to be able to select the worklist from a dropdown menu. I created a method in the form but its throwing an error. Here is my code:

from _form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :worklist_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :worklist_id, @worklists, :id , :name %>
</div>
```

from patient.rb:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worklist
end
```

from worklist.rb

```
class Worklist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients
end
```

from schema.rb

```
  create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "middlename"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.string   "sex"
    t.string   "ethnicity"
    t.string   "uniqueid"
    t.string   "accountnumber"
    t.string   "medicaidid"
    t.string   "medicareid"
    t.string   "ssn"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "worklist_id"
  end
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
NoMethodError in Patients#edit
undefined method `worklist_select'
```

Here is the PatientController:

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_patient, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /patients
  # GET /patients.json
  def index
    @patients = Patient.all
  end

  # GET /patients/1
  # GET /patients/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /patients/new
  def new
    @patient = Patient.new
  end

  # POST /patients
  # POST /patients.json
  def create
    @patient = Patient.new(patient_params)
    @worklists = Worklist.all

    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.save
        format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @patient }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /patients/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /patients/1
  # PATCH/PUT /patients/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.update(patient_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @patient }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /patients/1
  # DELETE /patients/1.json
  def destroy
    @patient.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to patients_url, notice: 'Patient was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

    def import
      Patient.import(params[:file])
      redirect_to patients_path, notice: "Patients Added Successfully"
    end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_patient
      @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def patient_params
      params.require(:patient).permit(:lastname, :middlename, :firstname, :birthdate, :sex, :ethnicity, :uniqueid, :accountnumber, :medicaidid, :medicareid, :ssn, :worklist_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Worklist.all` in the view is a problem. The view talking to the db directly is never good. That is the Controller's (or a Service's) job.

In your controller, you would want something like: `@worklists = Worklist.all`, then use `@worklists` in the view.

This is just a start though. Can you post your controller so we can help further?

**UPDATE**: Now we have a better idea of where this is going. Lets do this:

So in your PatientsController, you would want this in your create method:

```
@worklists = Worklist.all
```

Then in your `_form.html.erb` (from the patient folder NOT the Worklist folder), you would want:

```
<%= f.label :worklist_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :worklist_id, @worklists, :id , :name %>
```

Comment: I just posted my controller for you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I meant post your PatientsController. I'm assuming you're creating a new patient and then the dropdown will choose which worklist they belong to.

So in your PatientsController, you would want this in your create method:

    @worklists = Worklist.all

Then in your ```_form.html.erb``` (from the patient folder NOT the Worklist folder), you would want:

    <%= f.label :worklist_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :worklist_id, @worklists, :id , :name %>

Comment: I posted my PatientController up top with the changes you suggested and to the _form.html.erb. I am now get this error: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass. Could this been when my create method is executed in my controller?

Comment: Nevermind I had to put this in my edit and it worked as well. Thanks so much for the help. I think i got a clear understanding of how to make the calls now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just change this:

`<%= worklist_select( :patient, :worklist_id, Worklist.all, :id, :name, {}, {     :multiple => false } ) %>`

To something more like this:

`<%= f.select( :worklist_id, Worklist.all, :id, :name, {}, {     :multiple => false } ) %>`

You might get what you want.

Comment: As for the specific error you're getting, it's because you just invented a method out of the blue, afaict. Rails generates lots of good stuff for free, so I suppose it's worth a try, but not the particular method (`worklist_select`) that you were hoping for.

Comment: gave that a shot and it gave me an error: wrong number of arguments.